# Scipy website down - documentation mirror

Tags: scipy

For past two days I have been trying to access the scipy official site.
https://www.scipy.org/

I have not been able to access it. I have checked it on multiple service
providers as well as through boxes setup in US. I would trust this site to be 
official site and refer to documentation on it.

How does one intimate them ?
Also, meanwhile is there any mirror available for the documentation ?

Best Regards,
Vinayak

Comment: What do intend by `How does one intimate them ?`?

Comment: I meant, how does one communicate this to them or inform them.

Comment: You can try the Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20161216070200/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/

Comment: I think this question is pretty much off-topic, here :) Nevertheless, they *are* aware of the problem and working on it: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7171 , https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8779

Comment: @kazemakase Thanks for the links. I just did a quick search and found outdated issues only. Looks like a one-time *let's change something*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official mirror.

You can check the availability of the website via third party tools, such as http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/docs.scipy.org

The team behind SciPy is generally aware of the unavailability and do their best to put it back up.

The best "next" option is to build the docs yourself locally or rely on the `scipy-doc` package from your package manager. Under Debian, one can do `apt-get install python-scipy-doc` and look under `/usr/share/doc/python-scipy-doc/html`.

Answer (score 2):

The closest that I can reach till now:

http://web.archive.org/web/20161216070200/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/

Answer (score 0):

It looks it's best to use pydoc.

The most convenient form is to launch it in the browser using localhost http server. This can be done through pydoc -b and one can browse through
most of the relevant documentation for the specific package.